# Returning a value inside an if clause in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
_editor: function () {
  //retrieve all the editors on the current page
  var editors = window.tinymce.editors;
  var container = this.element;
  //pick one that's associated with current container
  $(editors).each(function (i, ed) {
    if (ed.id == container.id) {
      return ed; // even if this is invoked,
    }
  });
  // undefined is returned
}
```

I had to change the above code to

```
_editor: function () {
  //retrieve all the editors on the current page
  var editors = window.tinymce.editors;
  var container = this.element;
  var editor;      
  $(editors).each(function (i, ed) {
    if (ed.id == container.id) {
      editor = ed; // do not return yet. Store it.
    }
  });
  return editor; // return here
}
```

I assume this is because of JavaScript's scope characteristics. Could someone explain 1) if this is only inherent in JavaScript 2) what exactly is going on in each functional scope in the above code?

Thank you.

Comment: each just invokes the anonymous function that you passed. When you return in the scope of the anonymous function, it's returning from that invocation.

Comment: Using [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) would be more appropriate. (It will still iterate the whole collection, but will be cleaner code without requiring modification of a closed over variable.)

Comment: @user2864740: It really sounds as though jQuery is missing some useful methods, something equivalent to Underscore's `find`, or the equivalent in most functional languages.

Comment: @ScottSauyet It really sounds like Underscore is missing some useful methods like `$(..)` :-) The jQuery collection support is simply a mediocre extension of the mediocre (ES3) JavaScript methods. Anyway, ES6 (Harmony) should include [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @user2864740: Actually, this had me scrambling to see if **[Ramda](https://github.com/Crosseye/ramda)**, the JS functional programming library I've been developing already had this function.  I'm glad to say that it was already there!  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet There a few different "more functional" options these days. You may be interested in http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/ (not necessarily for production use). I thought it had some pretty neat concepts.

Comment: @user2864740: There are many, although Oliver Steele's -- the very first one -- is now more inspirational than practical.  Probably the best known ones right now are **[allong.es](http://allong.es/)** and **[lemonad](http://fogus.github.io/lemonad/)**, although there are many interesting ones, including a collection of stand-alone functions called **[cherries](https://github.com/casperin/cherries)** and the lazy list library **[Lazy](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/)**.  I'm hoping mine will eventually join the ranks of the biggies, but it needs a lot more work first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are returning a value from that anonymous function passed to `$(editors).each`, not the outer function. In the second case you are returning from the outer function.

This is how it works with pretty much any language that allows nested functions. `return` only returns from the innermost function.

Answer (score 3):

It returns from the function called by `each`:

```
 $(editors).each(function (i, ed) { // <---
    if (ed.id == container.id) {          |
      return ed; // <--- this exits this --
```

> is [this] only inherent in JavaScript[?]

No, many languages which use anonymous functions, also called lambdas, operate like this. A couple of examples are C# and ruby. Calling return exits themselves, rather than the functions they are invoked in.

> what exactly is going on in each functional scope in the above code?

```
$(editors).each(function (i, ed) {
    if (ed.id == container.id) {
      editor = ed; // do not return yet. Store it.
    }
  });
```

The function body is called once for each element `ed` in `$(editors)`. When the loop exits, the last value for which `ed.id == container.id` is then stored in `editor`. The second argument `i` is the index (0,1,2,3,...) incremented in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have nested functions. You have the function assigned to the `_editor` property, and within that you have a function that's being invoked by `$.each()`. The `return` statement returns from the closest containing function, so in the first example it's returning from the `$.each()` iteration function, not the `_editor` function.

`$.each()` uses the return value of the iteration function to determine whether to continue looping -- if the function returns `false`, it stops at that element (similar to using the `break;` statement in a `for` or `while` loop).

Answer (score 3):

> Could someone explain 1) if this is only inherent in JavaScript 2) what exactly is going on in each functional scope in the above code?

The code is returning from the function passed to `.each()`, so it doesn't impact the enclosing function.

You can use `$.grep` for a cleaner solution.

```
_editor: function () {
  //retrieve all the editors on the current page
    var editors = window.tinymce.editors;
    var container = this.element;

    return $.grep(editors, function (ed, i) {
        return ed.id == container.id;
    })[0];
}
```

This is basically a filter. The result will be the items in the collection where you returned a truthy value. And so we just return the first truthy result (index `0` of the result).